# Need a join where the link is based on a date range that needs to be calculated from second table

Tags: sql

I'm looking to extract a value from table 2 which was current at time of a transaction in table 1, but only have a valid_to attribute against each line in table 2

[image]

Apologies if this is painfully simple and I'm just being dim

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Sample data is better supplied as `create table` and `insert into` statements. Screen shots can not be copied and pasted into a SQL tool.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it (in SQL Server):

```
select t1.Payer, t1.[Transaction Date], t2.Status
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2
on t2.Payer = t1.Payer
and t2.[Transaction Date] = (
select min([Transaction Date]) 
from Table2 
where Payer = t1.Payer
and [Transaction Date] >= t1.[Transaction Date])
```